# Recursive constraints: What does DBase<T> : where T : DBase<T> mean?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I thought I understood generic constraints until I ran across this.

```
public class DBase<T> : DbContext, IDisposable where T : DBase<T>
```

How can T be `DBase<T>`?
And if it can, what does it mean?
This code compiles and runs fine. I'm not fixing a problem. I just don't understand it.

It is used here

```
    public class ChildDb : DBase<ChildDb>
```

Which, again, doesn't compute for me. It passes itself as a type parameter?

Comment: This way you can set all the generic methods to require T to be of the same type as the declaring type. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/simonince/2008/06/12/generics-the-self-referencing-generics-pattern/

Comment: This is known as the [curiously repeating template pattern](http://www.codecutout.com/blog/curiously-repeating-template-pattern/) or CRTP.

Comment: Fascinating. Do you want to post either of these as an answer so I can acknowledge it?

Comment: It's usually useful for creating fluent builders having chainable methods. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53983914/3110834) you see, this pattern is useful to let the base class, have a method which returns the derived class instance.

Comment: Any of the three of these seem to be valid answers. I'll wait a week and see which is upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can `T` be `DBase<T>`?

There is no limitation that prevents a Generic Parameter from deriving from itself.  While it's not directly understandable with the example you've given.  What about a [Vertex / Vertice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_(geometry))?

Excerpt from Wikipedia:

[image]

> In geometry, a vertex (plural: vertices or vertexes) is a point where two or more curves, lines, or edges meet. As a consequence of this definition, the point where two lines meet to form an angle and the corners of polygons and polyhedra are vertices.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cweZm.png)

How does one describe a Vertex (a point)?

```
// very simplified example
public class Vertex
{
  public int X { get; set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Now how do we add a collection of relationed Verticies to this class but only allow things that derive from this class?

```
public class Vertex<TVertex> : Vertex
  where TVertex : Vertex<TVertex>
{
  public IEnumerable<TVertex> Vertices { get; set; }
}
```

It a generic version of say:

```
public Vertex2
{
  public IENumerable<Vertex2> Vertices { get; set; }
}
```

However when I derive from Vertex2, my `Vertices` will always have to be `IEnumerable<Vertex2>`, and the correct way to allow Vertices to be a derived class is to use this type of self-reference generic.

> I'm sorry Erik, I lost the point in the details. What have I gained by the recursion?

Using `Vertex2`, our derived types lose *access* to other derived properties:

```
public class MyVertex2: Vertex2
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

so

```
var a = new MyVertex2 {Id = 1 };
var b = new MyVertex2 { Id = 2 };
a.Vertices = new List<Vertex2> { b };
b.Vertices = new List<Vertex2> { a };

// can't access Id because it's a Vertex2 not a MyVertex2
var bId = a.Vertices.First().Id;
```

Sure you could cast it, but then you're casting it everywhere (that's not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))... and what if it's not a MyVertex (MullReferencesException or InvalidCastException).

```
public class MyVertex: Vertex<MyVertex>
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
var a = new MyVertex {Id = 1 };
var b = new MyVertex { Id = 2 };
a.Vertices = new List<MyVertex > { b };
b.Vertices = new List<MyVertex > { a };

var bId = a.Vertices.First().Id;
// or even
var aId = a.Vertices.First().Vertices.First();
```

each time we navigate to a vertices we get the *correct* derived type, not the base class.

Comment: Good example but requires knowledge of Mathematics :)

Comment: I'm sorry Erik, I lost the point in the details. What have I gained by the recursion? Wouldn't this be better: "<T> where T: Vertex" where Vertex is the original class rather than the generic. I'm clearly still missing something.

Comment: @BWhite if it's not the generic class you can't navigate to any other Vertex, because you don't have the `Vertices` class.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for the clarification. To sum up, it's all about the class being able to use the correct descendant type. I was just looking at the code instead of how it was called.

Answer (score 1):

John Wu posted a great blog in the comments, the TLDR of which is:

This code pattern allows you to declare a superclass that must be extended *(possibly not by you, if you're writing a library that other people will use)* in order to be used, but can have a bunch of methods/signatures *(written by you)* that return T when you write them but in practice will return objects of the child type *(not written by you/you cannot know)* so they can be used in a chained fashion (like the way most StringBuilder methods return the StringBuilder itself so the user can call .Append().AppendLine() ) without needing to be cast *(in the code not written by you)* from the parent type *(written by you)* to the child type *(not written by you)*

There's a caveat: it's not particularly useful because only the deepest child in an inheritance tree can be instantiated. Avoid using it

Answer (score 1):

As a useful example, it allows you to have some methods or properties in the base class which return derived type.

For example, in the fluent builders which have chainable methods, let's say we have a base builder which set some common properties. What should be the output type of these methods?

See the following example:

```
public abstract class Control
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
public abstract class ControlBuilder<TBuilder, TControl>
    where TBuilder : ControlBuilder<TBuilder, TControl>, new()
    where TControl : Control, new()
{
    protected TControl control;
    protected ControlBuilder()
    {
        control = new TControl();
    }
    public static TBuilder With()
    {
        return new TBuilder();
    }
    public TControl Build()
    {
        control;
    }
    public TBuilder Id(string id)
    {
        control.Id = id;
        return (TBuilder)this;
    }
}
```

Without having `ControlBuilder<TBuilder, TControl>` as a constraint for `TBuilder`, how you can return a `TBuilder` from `Id` method?

If you say ask why not return `ControlBuilder<TBuilder, TControl>`, because if you return it, after calling .Id("something") in method chains, it will not show derived class methods and it just will show methods of `ControlBuilder<TBuilder, TControl>`.

Let's say we create a `TextBoxBuilder` for building a `TextBox`:

```
public class TextBox : Control
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
public class TextBoxBuilder : ControlBuilder<TextBoxBuilder, TextBox>
{
    public TextBoxBuilder Text(string text)
    {
        control.Text = text;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Now we can use it as expected:

```
var txt = TextBoxBuilder.With().Id("textBox1").Text("Hello!").Build();
```

Comment: I know the example seems a bit complex, but if you try it in action and try to answer *Without having ControlBuilder<TBuilder, TControl> as a constraint for TBuilder, how you can return a TBuilder from Id method* you will see if you don't have that constraint, then after calling `TextBoxBuilder.With().Id("textBox1")` methods of `TextBoxBuilder` will not appear and you just see methods of base `ControlBuilder`. I suggest you to try it in action to get it better. Hope it helps :)